# Can I concate date to my string?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a profile form and when my user update their profile , the current date also will be added to the decription of the profile.

```
$today = Date("l F d, Y"); 

$sqlUpdate = 'UPDATE USER_PROFILE SET 
FIRST_NAME =("'.$FIRST_NAME.'"), 
LAST_NAME=("'.$LAST_NAME.'"), URL=("'.$URL.'"), 
DESCRIPTION= CONCAT_WS(',',"'.$today.'","'.$DESCRIPTION.'") 
WHERE ID = "'.$GetID.'";';
```

I'm not sure how I can concate date to string in php, I would appreciate any help :)

here is the erro:

```
Parse error: parse error, unexpected ',' on line 122
```

Comment: it says Parse error: parse error, unexpected ',' in /home/.. on line 122

Comment: "concate date to string in php"? The date() function (assuming you mean date() by "Date()" already returns a string that you concat with ".".

Comment: >>> ... CONCAT_WS(','," ...
the first comma here breaks your syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must escape the quote:

```
$today = Date("l F d, Y"); 

$sqlUpdate = 'UPDATE USER_PROFILE SET 
FIRST_NAME =("'.$FIRST_NAME.'"), 
LAST_NAME=("'.$LAST_NAME.'"), URL=("'.$URL.'"), 
DESCRIPTION= CONCAT_WS(\',\',"'.$today.'","'.$DESCRIPTION.'") 
WHERE ID = "'.$GetID.'";';
```

or you can just make the DESCRIPTION column receive its actual value:

```
$today = Date("l F d, Y") . $DESCRIPTION; 

$sqlUpdate = "
    UPDATE USER_PROFILE SET 
        FIRST_NAME = '$FIRST_NAME'
        , LAST_NAME = '$LAST_NAME'
        , URL= '$URL'
        , DESCRIPTION = '$today' 
    WHERE
        ID = '$GetID'
";
```

Comment: the prev one worked fine , thank you very much ... will accept your answer in few min. it doesn't let me to accept immediately ?!